# How to retrieve CheckBox value in Controller - Asp.Net MVC 3 and Jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, json

**Problem:** *Check box value display null in controller.cs.* but it is working perfectly according to selection of row from jqgrid. But when I select any row and update all the field it will pass to the controller with modified value but only IsEnabled field comes null.

**I have Database Field called IsEnabled which has Bit data type.**

I have written following code in .cshtml

```
<input type="checkbox" value='Yes' offval='No' name="IsEnabled" />
```

I am using following code to bind check box value as per in database

```
grid.jqGrid('GridToForm', gsr, "#order");
```

I have save button. When I click on save following code will execute

```
$("#btnSave").click(function () {
                var data = JSON.stringify($('#order').serializeObject());
                var href = '@Url.Action("SaveData", "Users")';
                var ajaxResponse = $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: href,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: data,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.Success == true) {
                            alert("Success");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Error: " + result.Message);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Following code written in Controller.cs

(**in FormValue it will show all the updated value correctly except IsEnabled, it will display always null.**)

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult SaveData(User FormValue)
        {
            string message = "";
            return Content(message);
        }
```

Comment: this blog post may help you http://blog.ecofic.com/?p=346

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, **but it couldn't resolved my issue because i am using Model instead of FormCollection**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must delete this code ( if use jquery ajax )

`[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]`

when you use post back and send class use above code

send class with jQuery use this code:
try it:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: href,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: SON.stringify({ FormValue : { ID : $('#controlIdName').val() , Name : $('#ControlName').val() } }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.Success == true) {
                        alert("Success");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Error: " + result.Message);
                    }
                }
```